# Access remote network devices through OpenVPN

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, openvpn, synology

I'm attempting to use a VPN to access remote network devices, while blocking off those devices from the internet. I've set the firewall (on a Synology NAS) to allow accessing those ports from a local IP address (192.168.0.0, 255.255.255.0), which should allow users on the VPN to access them too, as I understand it.

Manually allowing remote IPs through the firewall has worked, but isn't a permanent solution since the main location which needs access doesn't have IPv4.

The firewall rules look something like this:

```
Allow all connections to 1192 (VPN)
Allow local connections to any port
Deny everything else
```

The VPN should be accessible from anywhere, and any port from only local devices -- otherwise, deny the connection. Being on the VPN from a remote device is supposed to allow access to any port through the "local connections" firewall rule.

Am I misunderstanding the usage of VPNs to access devices on a remote network?
Secondarily, does this sound like an issue with the firewall or the OpenVPN configuration?

Thanks in advance.